# Passing parameters from function to its callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code:

First the execution of the program comes here:

```
refreshTree(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ControllerName/MethodName1",
                success: function (data) {
                    refresh();
                }
            });
        });
```

Here's the definition of `refreshTree()`:

```
function refreshTree(callback) {
    var isOk = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ControllerName/MethodName2",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == 'True') {
                isOk = false;
            }
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

And here's the `refresh()` method:

```
function refresh() {
    if (isOk) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

The problem is, I don't know how to get the `isOk` variable in `refresh()`. Is there some way to send the variable to `refresh()`, without it being a global variable?

Comment: *"Is there some way to send the variable to refresh(), without it being a global variable?"* Simply pass the value as argument to the callback. Define the callbacks/functions to accept an argument.

Comment: why cann't you pass it as parameter to `refresh` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You capture it in a closure here:

```
refreshTree(function(isOk) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ControllerName/MethodName1",
        success: function (data) {
            refresh(isOk);
        }
    });
});
```

And pass it in here:

```
function refreshTree(callback) {
    var isOk = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ControllerName/MethodName2",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == 'True') {
                isOk = false;
            }
            callback(isOk);
        }
    });
}
```

and here:

```
function refresh(isOk) {
    if (isOk) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply Pass it as parameter:

```
refreshTree(function(status) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ControllerName/MethodName1",
            success: function (data) {
                refresh(status);
            }
        });
    });
```

refreshTree() function:

```
function refreshTree(callback) {
var isOk = true;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/ControllerName/MethodName2",
    success: function(data) {
    var isOk=true;
        if (data == 'True') {
            isOk = false;
        }
        callback(isOk);
    }
});
```

}

Refresh() method:

```
function refresh(status) {
if (status) {
    //do something
 }
}
```